# Regular Expression without lookahead and lookback (golang package does not allow it)

Tags: regex

I have a working regular expression with negative lookahead and lookback `(?:^_(?!_))(.*)(?:(?<!_)_$)` for the following cases:

```
_john_              # matched
_status_            # matched
_aa_                # matched
_a_                 # matched
_john_smith_        # matched
_@_                 # matched
___test__           # not matched
__john_             # not matched
__john_smith_       # not matched
_john___            # not matched
_john_smith__       # not matched
__john__            # not matched
__john_smith__      # not matched
anything            # not matched
```

I want to match all cases that start and end with a single `_`, all other cases shouldn't be matched.

In golang the `regexp` package doesn't have lookahead and lookback implemented. How to translate the above regular expression to a golang-compliant one?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Something such as the following might work:

```
^_[^_]_$|^_[^_].*?[^_]_$
```

**Example**:

https://regex101.com/r/2iuIgi/1